# How can I configure list styles in CKEditor5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

we have a requirement where we have to remove one list style from CKEditor 5
Currently if list properties plugin is enabled, then following 6 list styles are available in CKE 5.

1. decimal
2. decimal-with-leading-zero
3. lower-roman
4. upper-roman
5. lower-latin
6. upper-latin

but we have a requirement where we don't want to show **decimal with leading zero** list style to the user. Is there anyway I can configure it? Is it configurable?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no official way of disabling it, as it comes included in the core of the plugin.

Possible way is that you customize the editor as you want it, you can find it [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/advanced/alternative-setups/integrating-from-source.html).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to replace the original menu items with a custom version that uses the commands of the original plugin in the background.

```
import Plugin from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin";
import ButtonView from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/button/buttonview";
import {Locale} from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils";
import numberedListIcon from "../theme/icons/numberedlist.svg";
import bulletedListIcon from '../theme/icons/bulletedlist.svg';
import listStyleDecimalWithLeadingZeroIcon from '../theme/icons/liststyledecimalbubble.svg';
import {Command} from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core";

export default class CustomListStyle extends Plugin {
  init() {

    const editor = this.editor;
    const numberedListCommandName = 'numberedList';
    const bulletedListCommandName = 'bulletedList';
    const listStyleCommand = editor.commands.get( 'listStyle' )!;

    function onChange(parentCommand: Command, button: ButtonView, type: string, isDefault: boolean) {
      let hasValue = false
      if (parentCommand.value) {
        hasValue = true;
      }
      button.isOn = listStyleCommand.value === type || (isDefault && listStyleCommand.value === 'default' && hasValue);
    }

    function getToolbarButton({
      type,
      label,
      isDefault,
      buttonIcon,
      parentCommandName
      }:{
      type: string,
      label: string,
      isDefault: boolean,
      buttonIcon: string;
      parentCommandName: string
    }) {
      return ( locale: Locale ) => {
        const button = new ButtonView();

        button.label = label;
        button.tooltip = true;
        button.icon = buttonIcon;

        const parentCommand = editor.commands.get( parentCommandName )!;

        listStyleCommand.on('change:value', () => {
          onChange(parentCommand, button, type, isDefault);
        });
        parentCommand.on('change:value', () => {
          onChange(parentCommand, button, type, isDefault);
        });
        button.bind('isEnabled' ).to( parentCommand, 'isEnabled' );

        button.on('execute', () => {
          // If the content the selection is anchored to is a list, let's change its style.
          if (parentCommand.value) {
            // If the current list style is not set in the model or the style is different than the
            // one to be applied, simply apply the new style.
            if (listStyleCommand.value !== type) {
              editor.execute('listStyle', {type});
            }
            // If the style was the same, remove it (the button works as an off toggle).
            else {
              editor.execute(parentCommandName);
            }
          }
          // Otherwise, leave the creation of the styled list to the `ListStyleCommand`.
          else {
            editor.model.change(() => {
              editor.execute('listStyle', {type});
            });
          }
        });

        return button;
      }
    }

    editor.ui.componentFactory.add( 'customNumberedListDecimal', getToolbarButton({type:'decimal', label: "Numbered list (circle)", isDefault: true,buttonIcon: numberedListIcon, parentCommandName: numberedListCommandName}));
    editor.ui.componentFactory.add( 'customNumberedListRoman', getToolbarButton({type:'upper-roman',label: "Numbered list (roman)", isDefault: false, buttonIcon: listStyleDecimalWithLeadingZeroIcon,  parentCommandName: numberedListCommandName}));
    editor.ui.componentFactory.add( 'customBulletedList', getToolbarButton({type:'disc',label: "Bulleted list", buttonIcon: bulletedListIcon, isDefault: true, parentCommandName: bulletedListCommandName}));
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ DocumentListProperties,CustomListStyle, /* ... */ ],
        toolbar: [ 'customNumberedListDecimal','customNumberedListRoman', 'customBulletedList' /*, 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', ... */ ],
    } )
    .then( /* ... */ )
    .catch( /* ... */ );
```